# Auto advance to the next page after completing Captcha verifiction on Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, captcha, qualtrics

What JavaScript would allow me to automatically advance to the next survey page after successfully completing Captcha verification. A the moment, one needs to click on the "Next" button after completing Captcha verification to proceed.

Best,
Marta

I have tried to look for a JavaScript that would allow me to auto-advance after successful Captcha verification on the Internet but so far have not found an answer.

Comment: Try looking for an event being fired after the Captcha has been verified. And it's true, take the user to the next page as if he would click Next